# Can you make image or part of it clickable ? ( The image itself, not using HTML, so it stays clickable when shared on FB for example)

Tags: image, image-processing, hyperlink

Is it possible to embed the link in the image itself ?

I understand making image clickable using HTML, but I want to make the image file itself clickable (at least when shared online).

http://www.thinglink.com/ is making interactive images, but they are adding javascript, thus making it unsharable on facebook ( you can share the image itself but it wont be clickable).

Thanks.

Comment: I hope not, spammers would use this like crazy

Comment: I am thinking more in a way that you can click on persons shoes on an image, which then takes you to "Buy that shoes" page.

Comment: Not on the image file. You could use Flash for that tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately (or maybe, fortunately) this is not possible. An image is, in essence, just an array of colored dots which is completely independent of something like the internet.